# Mongodb deleteMany, how to save disk usage?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that is quite big, see the screenshot of `db.action_traces.stats()`:

[image: action_traces stats]

I run `db.action_traces.deleteMany({ "block_time": { "$lt": "2018-08-15T00:00:00.000Z" } })` and `db.action_traces.deleteMany({ "block_time": { "$lt": "2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z" } })`

And got the following results:
`{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 5151786 }`
`{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 16261351 }`

But when I run `db.action_traces.stats()` again I get the following result `"storageSize" : 630196023296`. So basically, I've removed a big chunk of data but didn't save a single bit... how is that possible?

What can I do to save some space?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB storage files do not shrink -- instead, they have "holes" that get reused as you continue to add more data -- at least, thats how it used to be with the original mongodb db engine before they bought another company/engine.
In any case, the only way to shrink the files is to re-create them from scratch.  If you are running as a replica set you can bring down your node, delete your files, and bring the node back up -- the files will be written afresh without storage holes.  Its been a few years since I have done it -- read the documentation before you go down this path.  Either way, the mongodb storage does not "shrink" -- that much I remember.

(I have just looked at your screen shot again and noticed that you are using the new wired tiger db engine?  My answer refers to the "original" pre-wiredtiger behavior -- but perhaps its the same behavior in the new engine as well)

Comment: Many thanks for that comment, so what you're telling me is that any new data should just fill in the holes and not extend the disk storage? I'm asking because I'm running low and need to be cautious (I'm planning on migrating to another server but for cost efficiency, the later the better ;)).

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/:

> On WiredTiger, compact attempts to reduce the required storage space for data and indexes in a collection, releasing unneeded disk space to the operating system. The effectiveness of this operation is workload dependent and no disk space may be recovered. This command is useful if you have removed a large amount of data from the collection, and do not plan to replace it.
>
> compact may require additional disk space to run on WiredTiger databases.

So for your collection it must be

```
db.runCommand ( { compact: 'action_traces' } )
```

Comment: Wonderful, I wasn't aware of that command many thanks... I've run it but it didn't save much space unfortunately :( I've deleted 2/3 of the documents but on saved like 5%... I guess there is nothing else I can do?

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how deletion of 21 mln documents out of 1,8 bln is 2/3. It's just a little bit more than 1% to me.